# validate semver version in package.json dependency value

Tags: node.js, regex, npm, semantic-versioning

I am getting problems like this when validating that the right version of a dependency is installed:

```
package with name csvtojson is not satisfied. Installed version: 0.4.5 desired version: github:Keyang/node-csvtojson#16ba2237e0bd96d6e3773e4c4d6e36c70efa620e
```

I am trying to use the semver package to validate a desired dependency version:

```
const semver = require('semver');
const satisfies = semver.satisfies(installedVersion, desiredVersion);
```

in package.json, we might see this:

```
"csvtojson": "^1.12.0"
```

or

```
"csvtojson":"github:Keyang/node-csvtojson#16ba2237e0bd96d6e3773e4c4d6e36c70efa620e"
```

what I want to do is determine if an installed dependency meets the version range of the desired dependency.

If the desired version is not semverish, I am willing to skip it, but I don't have a good test for that, anyone have a good idea how to skip desired versions that don't appear to be semverish?

Maybe use a regex like this:

```
/.*[0-9]{1,5}\.[0-9]{1,5}\.[0-9]{1,5}/
```

?

Comment: Your regex is too simplistic. There's a known good/tested regex awaiting a merge into the semver site you may find useful: https://github.com/semver/semver/pull/460

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks, what about semver versions that start with tilde or caret? do I have to clean them first with `semver.clean()`?

Comment: The referenced regex is a starting point. It only covers the isolated semver string itself. Shouldn't be too difficult to add/test what you need. Follow the links to the related issues connected to the PR and you'll find references to regex test pages and plenty of test data.

Comment: Please do post your final solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

This RegExp here is validating all scenarios:

```
^(\d|[1-9]\d*)\.(\d|[1-9]\d*)\.(\d|[1-9]\d*)(-(0|[1-9A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*|[0-9]*[A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*)(\.(0|[1-9A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*|[0-9]*[A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*))*)?(\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?$
```

Source: https://brunorb.com/untangling-semver/